# Compressing binary data

Tags: c#, .net, compression

On one of the working steps of my algorithm I have a big array of binary data, that I want to compress.
Which algorithm (or may be, standard class) can you advise to use to compress the data as much efficient as possible?
**EDIT:**
The data firstly represented as `byte[n]` of `0` and `1`. Then I join every 8 bytes into 1 and get `byte[n/8]` array.

Comment: that depends on the nature (and in particular the density) of the data; for dense/random data, "compression" generally makes it *bigger*; so: what is the data?

Comment: Can you pls tell what is inside it: video, audio, image or something else?

Comment: Let's say this: try to zip the data (or rar it). If it compresses well, then you can hope to compress it. Otherwhise forget.

Comment: Not sure what to make of that edit. It doesn't tell us anything about the nature of the data.

Comment: Simple array of `0` and `1`. No multimedia data, no text. Just result of my algorithm working. There is no matter what data is. I just want to compress it without any data lost.

Comment: "Simple array of 0 and 1" and "join every 8 bytes into 1" sounds like you just described binary... still, as Darin says: try GZipStream and DeflateStream - they *might* compress; they *might* make it bigger. Isn't it fun?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) or the [`DeflateStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) are pretty standard classes to be used in such situations.

Obviously depending on the *binary data* you are trying to compress you will have better or worse compression ratio. For example if you try to compress a jpeg image with those algorithms 
you cannot expect very good compression ratio. If on the other hand the binary data represents text it will compress nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) and [SharpZLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) . The .NET "base" libraries (`GZipStream`/`DeflateStream`) are stream-based (so they compress a single stream of data. A stream is not a file, but let's say that the **content** of a file can be read as a stream). DotNetZip is more similar to the classic `PkZip/WinZip/WinRar`